# Python 2.7 function imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythonxy

When I say `import numpy as np`, I can access all the modules and submodules in numpy from np. I do not have to say `np.matrixlib.matrix`. What is this feature called? How do I implement this in my package.

Comment: I don't think your statement " I can access all the modules and submodules in numpy from np" is correct (I am not quite sure what you mean exactly), but consider `np.random.normal` which cannot be accessed through `np.normal`

Comment: You could just check how numpy [does it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one want's that submodules are available in the main module, they have to be imported in `__init__.py`.

See for example `numpy/__init__.py`:

```
from .matrixlib import *
```

imports everything from `numpy.matrixlib` into `numpy`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean something like:

```
from numpy import *
```

Although I think this may only do the first level of functions. You might need another one for the 'deeper' functions:

```
from numpy.matrixlib import matrix
```

Comment: Doing `import numpy as np` enables one to write`np.matrix` instead of having to import it seperately